# Simple Dojo Pop Up Window

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I'm working on my first web application using the JS API and am looking to add a simple tabbed pop-up window that can be called on the load of the page that can display map instructions and a general data disclaimer.  For the life of me I can't figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html and see the  Terms and Conditions Dialog example. Hope it will help you.You need to define few references (on top) +code (in middle part) + (at end) update the div tag

Comment: I always find Dojo to be a bit fiddly to get working to begin with so if you can't get the example from @Sunil to work then post the code you have and we can help you get up and running.